# Proof that when $\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n=+\infty$,$\lim_{n \to +\infty} b_n=-\infty$, then $\lim_{n \to +\infty}a_nb_n=-\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

This is a calculus homework question, I know how to prove if $ \lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n=A$ and $\lim_{n\to -\infty}=B$ then $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_nb_n=AB$. But does $+\infty \cdot -\infty$ really make sense?

I'm kind of stuck. Would appreciate any help :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Take $M<0$. If $n$ is large enough, then $a_n>\sqrt{-M}$ and $b_n<-\sqrt{-M}$. What does this tell you about $a_nb_n$ if $n$ is large enough?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you take $M<0$ when you use $-M$?

Comment: I think (but I might be wrong) that several authors define the meaning of $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=-\infty$ as$$(\forall M<0)(\exists N\in\mathbb N)(\forall n\in\mathbb N):n\geqslant N\implies c_n<M.$$

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should just write down the definitions...

1. $\lim a_n b_n = -\infty$ if
   $$
   \forall_{M>0} \exists_p: n > p \Rightarrow a_n b_n < -M
   $$
2. $\lim a_n = +\infty$ if
   $$
   \forall_{M>0} \exists_p: n > p \Rightarrow a_n >M
   $$
3. $\lim b_n = -\infty$ if
   $$
   \forall_{M>0} \exists_p: n > p \Rightarrow b_n < -M
   $$

So, just fix some arbitrary $M>0$ and, considering 2. and 3. choose $p_1, p_2$ such that  $a_n > \sqrt{M}$ (for all $n>p_1$) and $b_n < -\sqrt{M}$ (for all $n>p_2$). Now you can see that for $p \ge \max\{p_1, p_2\}$, definition  1. is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does make sense. It is defined operation.
$$ (+∞) \cdot (-∞) = -∞$$
For your case if $$\lim_{n \to +∞} a_n= +∞ \ and \lim_{n \to +∞} b_n=-∞,$$
then $$\lim_{n \to +∞} a_n \cdot b_n= -∞.$$

Comment: I think the point of the exercise is to prove exactly what you are stating...

Answer (score 0):

By definition we have $\forall M_1,M_2$

- $\forall n\ge n_1\quad a_n\ge |M_1|$
- $\forall n\ge n_2\quad b_n\le -|M_2|$

therefore by $n_0=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$ and $|M|=|M_1M_2|$

- $\forall n\ge n_2\quad a_nb_n\le -|M|$